# passing element of dynamic multidimensional array to a function

Tags: c, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I have code which already works but am trying to extend it.

```
unsigned char **data_ptr;
```

Allocate memory for the first "array"

```
data_ptr = (unsigned char **)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char **) * no_of_rows);
```

Then in a loop initialize each row

```
data_ptr[index] = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*), rowsize));
```

I then pass the address of my array to a library function. It works fine if I just pass the start of a row...

```
LibFunction( info_ptr,  &data_ptr[index] )  //OK
```

But I need to pass the address of where in a row I want the function to begin writing data. 
These both compile but fail in operation

```
LibFunction( info_ptr,(unsigned char **)data_ptr[index] + 1);
```

or..

```
LibFunction( info_ptr,(unsigned char **)data_ptr[index][1]);
```

LibFunction is of the form

```
LibFunction(..., unsigned char **)
```

I'm allocating more memory than I need with rowsize so I don't think I'm overrunning the array. As I stated, the code works fine if I pass it the start of a row but bugs out if I
try to pass any other element. There may be something else wrong but I need to know first if my syntax is ok.

Can't find anything else on the net as regards passing the address of single element of dynamic 2d array.

Comment: Are all rows are equal in size? If so, do yourself a favor and allocate one big array for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
LibFunction( info_ptr,(unsigned char **)data_ptr[index] + 1);
```

is wrong because `data_ptr` is an `unsigned char **`, so `data_ptr[index]` is an `unsigned char *`. Leave out the cast and correct the function you're calling, it should accept an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: The horrible casting was an attempt to correct compile errors.  But your comment regarding correcting the function hit the nail on the head and let me see what the real problem was.  I couldn't change the function (third party library) but I did manage to locate another function in the header files which did the same job but accepted a variable with one less level of indirection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections in your program, observed from the top few lines

Since,

```
unsigned char **data_ptr; // a pointer to a char pointer
```

get the sizeof(char*)  and always avoid typecasting the pointer returned by malloc()

```
data_ptr = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * no_of_rows);
```

And for doing the allocation for the rows,

```
data_ptr[index] = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*)* rowsize));
```

To pass the address of where in a row you want the function to begin writing data, change the function signature as

```
LibFunction(..., unsigned char *)
```

Comment: How do I avoid typecasting the pointer returned by malloc?  I now have my code working but still have to rely on the casts.

Comment: If you are using C and If your lvalue is of right type, you need not do typecasting. we have the implicit type cast behaviour of void* returned by malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
unsigned char* ptr = &data[0][1];
LibFunction(info_ptr, &ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `LibFunction(&data_ptr[row][start_here])`, exactly the same as if it was just an `unsigned char[ROWS][COLUMNS];`.

In general, it is my experience that if you think you require casts in modern-day C, it is probable that you are muddled up with what you are trying to do. A nice read is a [comment](http://wordaligned.org/articles/two-star-programming) on a post by Linus Torvalds on /. on this kind of stuff.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm compiling as C++.  The casts are in response to compile errors.  And you're right, I will read that Torvald document.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating room for `no_of_rows` pointers to pointers; there's an asterisk too many in there. Also, you really [shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C][1].

Your first allocation should be:

```
data_ptr = malloc(no_of_rows * sizeof *data_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`But I need to pass the address of where in a row I want the function to begin writing data`

So let's start simple, to make an array the correct size, forget trying to get the `sizeof` a complex type, we can simply do this:

```
unsigned char **data_ptr;
data_ptr = malloc(sizeof(data_ptr) * no_of_rows); //Just sizeof your var
```

Now you've got the correct memory malloc'd next you can malloc the memory for the rest easily:

```
for(index = 0; index < no_of_rows; index++)
  data_ptr[index] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * rowsize);
```

Last point, now that we've got all that set up, you should initialize your array:

```
for(index = 0; index < no_of_rows; index++)
  for(index2 = 0; index2 < rowsize; index2++)
     data_ptr[index][index2] = 0;
```

As for your function, you want it to take a "portion" of an array, so we need it to take an array and a size (the length of the array to initialize):

```
void LibFunction(unsigned char data[], int size);
```

Then we're your ready to store some data it's as easy as:

```
LibFunction(&data_ptr[1][2], 3);  // store data in second row, 3rd column, store
                                  // three values.
```

Comment: As stated in comment above, I'm dealing with a third party library so can't change the function, at least not without a recompile and explaining to my boss why I need to recompile a networked library!!